# asdf doesn't install nodejs

Tags: node.js, asdf-vm

Any help please. I'm not sure what I did, but I can't install or run nodejs using [asdf](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf).

```
$ asdf install nodejs 6.12.3
nodejs 6.12.3 is already installed
$ node
nodejs 6.9.4 not installed
$ which node
/home/sam/.asdf/shims/node
```

I have no clue. It says that is install but it does not run.
Greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the default node version from `6.9.4` (not installed as per the error message) to the installed version `6.12.3.`  You can do this using the *nvm* `alias` command.  If you don't have *nvm* installed, you can start [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation).

---

```
> nvm alias default 6.12.3
> node -v
6.12.3
```

Answer (score 2):

did not see the node version, sorry

```
$asdf local nodejs 6.12.3
```

Greetings!